# how to solve problem in sending an empty attachment

Tags: flutter

i want to send an attachment which is located in the folder lib
this is the code :

```
  sendEmail() async {
    String username = '***********';
    String password = '*********'; //Your Email's password;

    final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
    print(smtpServer);

     var  filename = 'hello1.txt';

    final message = Message()
      ..from = Address(username)
      ..recipients.add('******@gmail.com') //recipent email

      ..subject = 'SEND OF FILE WITH TEXT ' //subject of the email
      ..text = 'Hello \n  :) this a file with text '
      //body of the email
      ..attachments = [FileAttachment(File(filename))
]
      ;
    try {
      final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
      print('Message sent: ' +
          sendReport.toString()); //print if the email is sent
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print('Message not sent. \n' +
          e.toString()); //print if the email is not sent
      // e.toString() will show why the email is not sending
    }
  }
```

in my email i get an empty file and also on terminal it shows this error :

> E/flutter (10876): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =
> 'hello1.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

when i change the filename with another path it does not work also

Comment: You are getting a file not found exception meaning the file doesn't exist, that is completely different from a file that is empty

Comment: but in the email that i receive i get an empty one with the same name i guess it doesn't found it so it created a new one .